# Make div scrollable in Y when in landscape mode

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow

I'm having this issue with my notification container in my app. When the site is visited in a device in landscape mode the notification content is cropped. If I use `overflow:auto` the scroll doesn't work at all.

[image]

[image]

So I'm looking for a way to make the div scrollable when it is used in landscape mode. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please provide a [repro] for debugging details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overflow in this example works only if you have a defined height. For  example `max-height: 100%;` or `height: 100vh;`.

Your height should be the height of the screen minus the header. You could use height + the calculation operator.

For example:

```
max-height: calc(100% - 50px);  
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: `height: 100%` also only works if you have a defined height not a calculated one...

Comment: @tacoshy It works when the position of the element is fixed/absolute, I assumed it is in this case

Comment: Thanks, that made the trick